# wrong partition space allocation

Tags: linux, rhel

I have installed Linux with automatic space allocation and now i am facing space issue on / folder. My all installations are in / folder but whole space is showing in home , i want to find some way to move space from /home to / folder, i have used 
`df -h` command and the output is as below

```
# df -h
Filesystem             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/rhel-root   50G   43G  7.1G  86% /
devtmpfs                12G     0   12G   0% /dev
tmpfs                   12G  244K   12G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                   12G   34M   12G   1% /run
tmpfs                   12G     0   12G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2             1014M  161M  854M  16% /boot
/dev/sda1              200M  9.8M  191M   5% /boot/efi
/dev/mapper/rhel-home  237G  158M  237G   1% /home
tmpfs                  2.4G   44K  2.4G   1% /run/user/1000
```

How can i allocate this space to / folder as `86%` is but alarming to things being stopped soon due to low space.

Output of lsblk

```
# lsblk
NAME          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda             8:0    0   300G  0 disk
├─sda1          8:1    0   200M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2          8:2    0     1G  0 part /boot
└─sda3          8:3    0 298.8G  0 part
  ├─rhel-root 253:0    0    50G  0 lvm  /
  ├─rhel-swap 253:1    0    12G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─rhel-home 253:2    0 236.8G  0 lvm  /home
sr0            11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Comment: Please also post the output of `lsblk`.

Comment: Please check the Update in question